# Template literal in interface based on other interface

Tags: typescript

I want to have an interface with keys based on other interface with added `_${number}` on the end. And currently I have something like that, but it is not protecting by creating too much fields or fields with the same beginning.

```
interface iA {
  first: number
  second: number
}

interface iB {
    [key: `${keyof iA}_${number}`]:
    | number
}

const shouldBePossible: iB = {
    first_1: 1,
    second_1: 1,
}

const shouldntBePossible: iB = {
    first_1: 1,
    second_1: 1,
    first_2: 2,
}

const shouldntBePossible2: iB = {
    first_1: 1,
}

const shouldntBePossible3: iB = {
    first_1: 1,
    first_2: 2
}
```

Is it even possible to make something like that?:

```
interface iC {
    `first_${number}`: number
    `second_${number}`: number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try ussing mapped objects instead of interfaces:

```
interface iA {
    first: number;
    second: number;
}

type iB = {
    [key in `${keyof iA}_1`]: number;
};

const a: iB = {
    first_1: 1,
    second_1: 1
}
```

Comment: It works the same like my example

Comment: @MonkeyD.Teach Yes!!! but it should not allow you to do examples 2, 3 and 4 from your question (ones marked as shouldntBePossible, shouldntBePossible2, shouldntBePossible3)